# How to display an image or text while PHP is processing a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything like this.

I want to display an image or text to the user while a form is being submitted, the form is sending values through the `$_POST` and being received in the same page to make a DBO insert and a file's upload (`move_uploaded_file`).

I'm not sure if this can be done with jQuery, JavaScript or even PHP, so I'm asking for any help you can provide me.

Things I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#content").empty().html('<img src="waiting.gif">');
   });
);
```

With this I can show the image when the user clicks the button form (`#btn`) but I don't know how to stop it and return it "back" to the form or how to display a message when the process has been completed.

Comment: Are you submitting the form with or without ajax?

Comment: Are you directly submitting the form using a normal browser POST? That’s not gonna work for what you want to do.  You’ll need to use AJAX and have it display a modal while it is waiting for the `success` to be returned.

Comment: @barjonah Without ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to wrap jQuery's AJAX POST function.

```
function POST(_url,_data,_container,success,anim) {
        var _loader = null
        var doAJAX = function() {
            $.post(_url,_data,success);
        };

        if(typeof anim===undefined) {
            doAJAX();
        } else if(_container!=null) {
            switch(anim) {
                case 'loading':
                    _loader = $("<div class='LoadingAnim' style='display:none;'></div>");
                    _container.empty();
                    _loader.appendTo(_container).fadeIn('fast',doAJAX);
                    break;
                case 'fade':
                    _container.fadeOut('fast',doAJAX);
                    break;
                case 'slide':
                    _container.slideUp('fast',doAJAX);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I add the `_container` parameter, which is the jQuery object for the div thats going to hold the content. The optional `anim` parameter can change the animation for clearing the container. Also, the loading image is achieved by inserting a div into the container after it is cleared. That div has a class that styles it to have the animated loading icon and be properly centered in its parent container. The `doAJAX` function used to be longer but I had to cut some out as it wasn't usefull to the answer, thats why it seems un-necessarily empty. If using any `anim` option besides "loading", make sure to reset the container to visible in the `success` function.

Use is like this

```
POST('some-script.php',{data: values},$('#containerToPrintTo'),function(data) {
     //Do some error checking or get the return from data and insert it.
     }, 'loading');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). You can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) or do it manually.

If you do not want to use AJAX... then you are not going to be able to detect when the form has been completely submitted. BUT, you can just show the same page and replace the form with your "message" after postback.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using AJAX and there is a full page postback, you don't have to worry about clearing the waiting image since the whole page will refresh.

But need to take care that you are not 'emptying' or deleting your form content/values before you submit and also verify that the ***#btn*** actually submits the form.

```
$("#btn").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //TODO:
    //INSERT YOUR WAITING IMAGE, WHICH CAN BE AN OVERLAY ON THE FORM
    //GET FORM (USING ID/NAME) AND SUBMIT
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this part: "//GET FORM (USING ID/NAME) AND SUBMIT". Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

```
function maskPage($) {

  var mask_div = document.createElement('div');
  $(mask_div).css({
    background: 'black',
    opacity: '0.7',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    display: 'none',
    zIndex: 100
  }).attr('id', 'page_mask');
  $('body').append(mask_div);    
}



 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn").click(function(){
      if($('#page_mask').length === 0) {
        maskPage($);
       }

       // do your work 
       $('#page_mask').fadeIn('fast');
       });
    );
```

call like this safely.You can play with background and opacity of div.